# Latex SVG with variable Text

Tags: svg

[-this question is a dublicate of a stackoverflow-question-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403902/latex-svg-with-variable-text)

I would like to write a document with figures containing variable text.

In the combination of SVG and Latex, I tried to acomplish this:

In Latex preamble I added:

`\newcommand{\mwhw}{HelloWorld}`

Then, in Inkscape I added the following:
[image: Inkscape-SVG]

After correct output to `Drawing.pdf_tex`, I included the Image in the latex-Document:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
\input{Zeichnung01.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

Finally, the Latex-Output looks like this:
[image: LatexOutput]

This is almost perfect.
The only thing missing is, that the font of the variable value is latex default, whereas the documents font is set differently (to OpenSans).

Any advice? Thank You.